# pentaho report designer libFormulaErrorValue

Tags: pentaho

I have a formula that takes value from query data

Now, I want to skip the formula if the query data is 0

Example: `[value1]-[value2]/[value1]*100`

If the [value1] is 0, skip the formula.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Pentaho Report Designer have build-in Formula Editor, which can greatly simplify your life when constructing these formulas. Not sure starting which version it available, but in 3.6.1 it's for sure.

Also in Pentaho Wiki you may find a useful page describing Formula Expressions: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Formula+Expressions

As for your particular issue, I think this formula should work:

=IF([value1] = 0; ""; [value1]-[value2]/[value1]*100)

Starting equal sign is required in each formula!

Comment: I've updated the formula based on Suribabu note about division to zero.

Answer (score 0):

By observing your formula, [value1] field is there in the denominator, there might be a chance to get zero(0) for that field. This is logical error. 
If you handle that one, you can overcome this error.

For your case this formula would work.

```
= ( [value1]-[value2]/ IF(OR(ISEMPTYDATA([value1]); [value1] = 0)  ;1;[value1]) )*100
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an error where I used one date type as type "Date" and another as "Date(SQL)" where I used the first parameter with format "Date" to derive the other parameter with format "Date(SQL)" through a formula. Which came back to bite me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).